# Running a script from user input in flask

Tags: python, flask

I'm using flask to create a webpage for a script I have written and want to ask the user for input, and whatever they input is run in the python script I have written, how can I do this?

Here is the flask page I have created

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, request, url_for
#from flask_script import Manager
import json
import connect
import requests
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch


app = Flask(__name__)

def elastic_search(text):
    es = Elasticsearch(['10.0.0.9:9200', '10.0.0.15:9200'])
    word = input(text)
    res = es.search(index="pastebin-*", doc_type='doc', body={"query": {"bool": {"must": [{"match": {"key": word}}]}}})
    return res

@app.route('/key', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def key():
    if requests.method == 'POST', 'GET':
       result = request.form['key']
       elastic_search(result)
return render_template('key.html')

@app.route('/result', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def result():
    if request.method == 'POST':
       result = request.form
    return render_template('result.html', result = result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run('0.0.0.0')
    app.run(threaded=True)
```

and here's the HTML

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Key</title>


    <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="styleshee$>

    <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/jumbotron-narrow/jumbotron-narrow.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../static/key.css" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="header">
        <h3 class="text-muted"><Key/h3>
      </div>

      <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Please Enter Pastebin Key</h1>
        <form class="form-signin">
        <form action="" method"post">
        <label for="Key" class="sr-only">Key</label>
        <input type="text" name="inputKey" id="inputKey" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required value="{{
      request.form.key }}">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        <<button id="btnEnter" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" formmethod="post">Enter</button>
      </form>
      {% if error %}
        <p class="error"><strong>Error:</strong> {{ error }}
      {% endif %}
      </div>



      <footer class="footer">
        <p>&copy; Point</p>
      </footer>

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and the HTML for the results page -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Results</title>


    <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/jumbotron-narrow/jumbotron-narrow.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../static/result.css" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>

  <body>
  <table border = 1>
     {% for key, value in result.res() %}

            <tr>
               <th> {{ resp }} </th>
            </tr>

         {% endfor %}
      </table>

      </form>
      {% if error %}
        <p class="error"><strong>Error:</strong> {{ error }}
      {% endif %}
      </div>

      <footer class="footer">
        <p>&copy; Intel</p>
      </footer>

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I know I'm not meant to post scripts like this but I couldn't figure out how to ask this with smaller snippets.

Answer (score 1):

Change your script to the function. And call the function when user entered something in the browser.

```
def elastic_search(text):
    word = input(text)
    res = es.search(index="pastebin-*", ...)
    return res

# View function
@app.route('/key', methods=['POST', 'GET'])      
def key():
    if requests.method == 'POST':
       result = request.form['key']
       resp = elastic_search(result)
    return render_template('key.html', resp=resp)
```

Comment: I appears to work when i run it but i get a 404 when i try to access it. Could it be the html?

Comment: Please explain what you wanted to see in the HTML and what is not working. I can explain the behaviour if you explain clearly.

Comment: I want a page where there is an input box and and enter button, the user inputs into the box then when they press enter it searches the script

Comment: Okay I see. You have `inputkey` in your HTML but in your view function you are try to get this `key` from request. Are you sure is this correct "?

Comment: so it should just say key rather than inputkey?

Comment: `inputKey` is the correct one. Please change your view function and let me know if this still not works

Comment: Can you update your question what you have changed so far based on our conversation? I will look into your question and give better suggestion to solve this issue. Are we good?

Comment: Ok there you go

Comment: Okay I told you to change the `key` to `inputKey`

Comment: `result = request.form['inputkey']`

Comment: It dosent display the result?

Comment: The question is where you wanted to show the results? If you want to show the results please pass the query output to template and show the result then

Comment: I've updated my question. Please change your template to include {{ resp }}

Comment: Could i do this on the same page?

Comment: where on the templates would i include {{ resp }}?

Comment: Anywhere you like. But Is that really a question? If then how you decided to include `{{ error }}` template tag in first place. Still curious... Please study Flask template jinja for better understatnding

Comment: Ive just edited it from what i think would solve my issue could you take a look please?

Comment: I don't know you tell me. Is it working ? because you only wrote that code

Comment: Bro you are confusing and the codebase is still wrong. I suggest you to take a look at Flask tutorial.

Comment: When you submit the information on the web page it accepts it but there is no output

Comment: I don't know man... I'm out of options but still your code look like mess.